# Twilio Studio Download Call Details

Tags: python, json, twilio

We ran a call flow for several days which captured data we can not export.
With python we can export the sid but it does not offer the details we are looking for.
Is there a way to download call detail which contains the SpeechResult?
When viewing the data we are attempting to capture through the web interface it's in a json format.

```
  "widgets": {
"split_intro_voice": {},
"Intro": {
  "Called": "+19999999999",
  "ToState": "FL",
  "CallerCountry": "US",
  "Direction": "inbound",
  "SpeechResult": "No.",
  "CallerState": "NV",
  "Language": "en-US",
  "ToZip": "99999",
  "Confidence": "0.96036434",
  "CallSid": "CA169f",
  "To": "+199999999",
  "CallerZip": "99999",
  "ToCountry": "US",
  "ApiVersion": "2010-04-01",
  "CalledZip": "99999",
  "CalledCity": "JACKSONVILLE",
  "CallStatus": "in-progress",
  "From": "+199999999",
  "AccountSid": "ACc33",
  "CalledCountry": "US",
  "CallerCity": "LAS VEGAS",
  "Caller": "+199999999",
  "FromCountry": "US",
  "ToCity": "JACKSONVILLE",
  "FromCity": "LAS VEGAS",
  "CalledState": "FL",
  "FromZip": "99999",
  "FromState": "NV"
},
```

Comment: The JSON you've posted there has a `SpeechResult` field within the `Intro`. Is that not what you're looking for? Where did you find this JSON?

Comment: It might be. How do I retune Intro? I've looked in the python library twilio I see base, compact, http, and rest. I've looked in each without luck. Where can I find Inntro? Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking there. What do you mean retune it? How did you get this JSON in the first place?